# Hiding column in print out from IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing

In our application we have a webgrid with a reference column which is never shown. The column is hidden via css, and this works just fine for all major browsers. When printing though, hiding the column the same way in our print.css as we do in the main.css, the column is hidden in Chrome, Firefox and IE up through IE8, but shows up in IE9.

Even more annoying, using the developer tools, if I switch both Browser Mode and Document Mode to IE8, the print works, and then switching both back to IE9, the print out hides the column correctly. This correct behavior persists until I close out of IE entirely. I know it has switched back to IE9 mode though because the formatting changes slightly between the versions. So for some reason, the expected behavior only shows up after switching back to IE9 mode from an older mode.

Here's the css I'm using to hide the column (it's the 11th column in the webgrid):

```
#gridRequestManagement table tr th + th + th + th + th + th + th + th + th + th + th
{
    width:0 !important;
    display:none !important;
}
```

Anybody have any insights on what's going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use `#gridRequestManagement table tr th:nth-child(11)`?

Comment: You are not hiding a column, you are hiding a cell with this "CSS"

Comment: @BramVanroy I'm not really a UI guy and wasn't the one that wrote this, I'm just the one that's trying to fix the defect, but what you're suggesting isn't anything other than cleaner syntax correct?

Comment: @EugeneXa Yes, that's correct, I'm hiding the header column because the body cells are already hidden. Given then that hiding the header results in hiding the column, I am using this to hide the column.

Comment: @Belizzle Correct, hence posting it as a comment.

Comment: What does CSS standard say about "hiding the header results in hiding the column"? I would just try to give display: none to all TDs just in case...

Comment: And it is much better to give a column meaningful class name instead of using magic number "11" to identify it

Comment: @EugeneXa I do give a name to the fields and set it in the css to display:none, but it only hides the TDs, not the TH. Hence why I need to hide the header to hide the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was never actually possible to resolve in the above manner, and it seems others have found the same issue and come to the same conclusion. To work around the issue, we removed the last column of the webgrid and added the value from the column as a hidden value on another column for reference. This was the only way we were able to get the grid to behave consistently in IE9.